# Function works but in console I get an syntax error

Tags: javascript

For debugging purpose I am using eval() like this:

```
function logInternal(type, msg) {
   eval("console." + type + "('" + msg + "')");
};
```

Function itself it works, problem is if console is active I still get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I know that eval is not recommended but anyway, any idea what is wrong? Thx

Comment: You can use `console['log']('msg')` instead not recommended `eval`

Comment: `logInternal('log', 'test')` [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/9fjw0kxa/). What are the values of `type` and `msg`?

Comment: You have to escape single quotes in `msg` if you're going to use your approach. I really would recommend [Nikitas version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509907/function-works-but-in-console-i-get-an-syntax-error#comment110547665_62509907) here.

Comment: Why even use `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. You could use the property with bracket notation without `eval`.

```js
function logInternal(type, msg) {
   console[type](msg);
}

logInternal('log', 'works!');
```

Comment: _"It works"_ - Not for every value of `msg`.

Comment: @Andreas, do you have an example?

Comment: @NinaScholz Assuming "_It works_" applies to OP's initial solution, calling ``logInternal('log', `'('`)`` will break.